# Fast clear MSXML Document or Re-create?

Tags: msxml

Is there a fast way to clear the previous content of an MSXML2.DOMDocument object prior to reuse?  I've been in the habit of discarding them and creating a fresh instance each time but this strikes me as wasteful and profiling a few test cases seems to confirm this.

I'm sticking with MSXML 3.0 in this case for portability, and I realize this older version has some quirks when it comes to using XPath to select large sets of nodes.  Trying to select the whole document tree and then removing it doesn't feel clean and doesn't run as fast as I'd like.  The "lazy selection" MSXML 3.0 uses doesn't inspire confidence either:

[selectNodes Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(VS.85).aspx)

> Previously, in MSXML 3.0 and earlier versions, the selection object created by calling the selectNodes method would gradually calculate the node-set. If the DOM tree was modified, while the selectNodes call was still actively iterating its contents, the behavior could potentially change the nodes that were selected or returned. In MSXML 4.0 and later, the node-set result is fully calculated at the time of selection. This ensures that the iteration is simple and predictable. In rare instances, this change might impact legacy code written to accommodate previous behavior.

I also realize that reusing such an object requires being mindful of the current settings of different properties (SelectionLanguage, etc.) that might linger between uses.  I'd think that shouldn't be a big deal though, especially if the reusage always follows the same pattern.

I suppose what I'm after then is some clean and fast way to clear the loaded DOM to reuse it, or more input as to why reuse might be worse than the alternative of recreation.

Comment: I'm no MSXML whiz, but have you tried calling Document->putref_documentElement (with a newly constructed, empty root element) or calling Document->load (with a pointer to a different XML source)?

Comment: Loading won't help becase I'm constructing the Document in code, but the other idea is worth trying.  Thanks!  Almost seems obvious, but maybe I haven't tried it.

Comment: Replacing the root element seems to do the trick.  Too bad this wasn't suggested as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider migrating to MSXML6:

1. First of all, MSXML6 is in-the-box with WinXP SP3, Vista, Windows
   Server 2008, Win7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. The only OS supported
   by Microsoft that doesn't have MSXML6 in band is Windows 2003, where
   you'll have to let customer to download the MSI. Overall, MSXML6 is 
   almost as portable as MSXML3.
2. Unlike MSXML3 supporting both XSL Pattern and XPath, MSXML6 supports XPath only, where SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode only work in the context of snapshot.
3. Unlike GetElementsByTagName, a snapshot semantics is a defined by W3C.
   MSXML6 has better performance and W3C compliance.

Also, you shouldn't care too much about cleaning up the document after each use, as MSXML has [Garbage Collection](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304227) internally, meaning you'll not get the memory back when you replacing the document element. My advice is to have peace with a specific cleansing effort, just reuse the instance for the next load or rebuilding the tree with DOM API. If memory usage is really a big concern, [XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can give you full control.

Comment: Your point regarding MSXML 6 is well taken, however there are still lots of Win2K and Win9X systems in the wild among my target PC base.  As far as "garbage collection" goes I think you are way wrong.  MSXML DOM is COM-based, so cleanup is useful (and effective) there, unlike something created in .Net or Java.  But if you have evidence to the contrary I'd appreciate a link.

Comment: Tried a quick benchmark, and there is no magic cleanup.  However there is "lazy cleanup" because checking immediately reveals only part of the memory is reclaimed.  To really clear the overhead means releasing the object entirely, not even .loadXML("") gets it all back.  My point in cleaning up at all is that I may load and use a large document, then wait a long time (minutes or hours) before needing another one - or I might construct another within milliseconds.  It all adds up when you're writing server side code that may have hundreds of clients.

Comment: Where you are now is what I am trying to help. MSXML is a COM with GC internally, as I've pasted the link, and that was a long story back to Visual J++. Anyway, I just provide the information to help you to choose the right solution in both platform and the strategy for cleanup. I don't think it worth a down vote.

Comment: The downvote was re. MSXML 6.  However I reconsidereed but by then it woud not let me undo the vote.  If you do a minor edit it will let me retract the down vote.

Comment: Reading the linked article, I'd even be glad to upvote now. Looks like a great reason to avoid the MSXML DOM entirely, and may explain a number of other erratic performance problems we're seeing with it.  I see their reasons, large object hierarchies are never cheap to clean up.

Comment: Edited. Glad that I helped. MSXML has memory issue for historical reasons, which should be improved for sure.

Comment: Too bad the sour taste of VJ++ still lingers, though its bitterness lives on of course in .Net.